# Confirm() always return true?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Confirm Delete
function confirms(id) {

   var test=confirm("Confirm Delete?");

   if(test== true)
       window.location="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&did="+id;
   else
       window.location="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&did="+id;
}
</script>
```

Comment: No need to do `if (test == true)`, that's redundant. Either do `if (test)` or `if (test === true)`. What you have is no good. Also, your `if` and `else` blocks are doing exactly the same thing (code is identical).

Comment: what is the difference between if and else statements both are doing the same thing.

Comment: thanks...here i managed it ...

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't always return true. Your script just always runs the same code regardless. It's equivalent to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Confirm Delete
function confirms(id) {
   window.location="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&did="+id;
}
</script>
```

Comment: function confirms(id)
    {
        var test=confirm("Confirm Delete?");
        if(test==true)
        {
            window.location="<?php echo ADMINURLPATH;?>managemenu&did="+id;
            return true;
        }
    }

Comment: its for nothing ....i just make changes to my code and it runs well..Anyways Thanks for your intrest....

Comment: That's good. Good luck with the rest of it!